# Making edit option in Redux - is it possible to do it without states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I wanted to know if I can somehow modify my code so to use only Redux in my App - it's about editing the item. I don't know how to do it without doing my state which determines if the edit form shows or not, I also don't know if I can somehow else provide the clicked item instead of doing `setChosenItem`.
Is it possible to do in clean Redux?

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {editTodo} from "../actions/TodoActions"
import {Field, Form, Formik} from "formik";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from "uuid";
const TodoList = ({todos,editTodo}) => {
const [shouldEdit,setShouldEdit] = useState(false)
    const [chosenItem,setChosenItem] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(chosenItem)
    })
    return (

        <div>
            {shouldEdit && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Todo edit: </h3>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{
                            id: chosenItem.id,
                            name: chosenItem.name,
                            date: chosenItem.date,
                            done: chosenItem.done
                        }}
                        onSubmit={(values) => {editTodo(values); setShouldEdit(!shouldEdit)}}
                        enableReinitialize={true}>
                        <Form>
                            <Field name="name" />
                            <Field name="date" />
                            <button type="submit">
                                Zatwierdz
                            </button>
                        </Form>
                    </Formik>
                </div>
            )}
            {todos.map(todo => (<div>{todo.name} <button onClick={() => {setShouldEdit(!shouldEdit);setChosenItem(todo)}}>Edit</button></div>))}
        </div>
    )


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    editTodo
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use states?

Comment: I wonder if the teacher allows me to do it if he said we shall use Redux, reducers instead of states

Comment: Redux is, in general, supposed to be used to keep track of states that are relevant in multiple different components, so that you don't need to use a massive amount of props in order to access those states. If a state is only to be used in one component, then it should use the useState hook, rather than redux. But if this is a school assignment, then maybe you have to ignore best practices and use redux anyway.